# Setting Emmet/live templates in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, emmet

When I write `img.logo` the output is

```html
<img src="" alt="" class="logo">
```

But I want to swap the position of the "class" attribute so it comes first:

```html
<img class="logo" src="" alt="" >
```

How can I do this?

Please, help. I searched for the information but could not find.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's not possible (for `img.logo` expansion).

1. Current behaviour matches the actual Emmet. Try it yourself at https://docs.emmet.io/actions/expand-abbreviation/
2. It was asked before (earlier this year) and JetBrains declined such a request with no plans of implementing such a customization: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55938

---

**P.S.** If it's just `img` expansion or another standard abbreviation (e.g. `img:s`, `img:sizes`, `img:z` etc) then you could change the underlying Live Template that is actually used for such predefined abbreviations (at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Live Templates` --> `Zen HTML` node). But it is not possible for dynamic expansion (with class names/ids etc).